# Why does javascript shows "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'Common' has already been declared after making javascript class object" in console?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

```
class Common
{
   constructor(){
    this.URL=location.protocol + '//' + location.host+'';
   }

    showOk(){
    console.log('ok');
    }

}
const commn=new Common();
```

Here is my html codes that I've tried to call the showOk() function.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-01 btn-checkout-login ml-auto w-100 text-center" onclick="return commn.showOk();" ;="">Continue Checkout</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-01 btn-checkout-login ml-auto w-100 text-center" onclick="commn.showOk();" ;="">Continue Checkout</button>
```

Comment: Code works fine as-is: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/q84ar0kg/ (and so far has nothing to do with laravel, php or jQuery) Can you create a [mre]?

Comment: whereever that class is being defined, it's probably being loaded twice ... or you have two different scraps of code that try to define a `class Common` ... either way, it's in code you haven't shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write like this, you need know, class's instance's function is different with normal function.

```html
<button onclick="handleClick();">click</button>

<script >

class Common {
   constructor(){
    this.URL=location.protocol + '//' + location.host+'';
   }

    showOk(){
     console.log('ok');
    }

}
const common = new Common();

function handleClick() {
  common.showOk();
}
</script>
```